# Removing " from string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string that has the value `/Daily"`. and the parameter that i'm trying to pass into my application is `/Daily`. However after trying a few methods to remove the quote, nothing seems to be working.

**Methods used**

- .remove('"');
- .replace("\"");
- .trim('"');

Comment: Use the other slash.

Comment: you must not be setting the string correctly. All of those return a string that has to be set. You also need to use a \ not a /.

Comment: I've updated the question. I did try \.

Comment: When asking a coding question you should show your code in question. Also StriplingWarrior's answer will help you.

Comment: Are you sure you asking question about C#? (closed as duplicate of C# questions, but now I'm not so sure). Your method calls look like Java - are you sure you've tagged post correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that strings in .NET are immutable, so calling the Replace method doesn't actually change the underlying string--it returns a value that represents a new string based on the Replace operation. You'll need to capture that returned value for this to work:

```
var str = "/Daily\"";
str = str.Replace("\"", "");
```

Also notice that quotes are escaped by backslashes (`\`) in C#, rather than forward-slashes.